# Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues while open the Android Studio in MacBook

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android Studio 3.1.3 
It works well earlier, but Today I am trying to open the android Studio in My MacBook Pro, I am getting the below exception.

I tried to open without internet.
Remove the android studio and installed again then restart. 
Restart My MacBook.
But not open the android Studio.

This is I am getting in the log without open the Android Studio.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:213)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:276)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
at
```

I have google it and didn't solve the problem.

please help me to find the Solution to start my android studio.

Thanks